# block property setting to non-block element

Tags: html, css

with the settings below, the css will do the trick in generate a horizontal menu bar perfectly for me.  anyway, I'm doubting to know, according to the third group stylesheet, even if its attribute has been set as block (the anchor tag). why doesn't it really behave as a block?

Since I learn from most css tutorials that a block is supposed to have a line break before and after the element. but in this case why they (all anchors) has been placed one next to another in the same line. I'm just curious and want to understand.

any explanation would be very much appreciated!

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 28px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
} 

li {
    float: left;
}

ul a {

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: block; 
    line-height: 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="menuBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>                     
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an `<li>` that is set to float left. I imagine your anchor tags are within your li tags. remove this rule:

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

And your `<a>` should be block level. By setting the `<li>` to float left, you are telling the browser to set a block element to stack against each other instead below one another.

Comment: does this mean css child elements do follow their parent's property value?

Comment: Yes this is what it means. Everything in CSS is inherited

Comment: @Michael Rader: Wrong. Not every property in CSS is inherited by default until you specify `inherit`, and `display` is one of those properties which isn't inherited by default.

Comment: @BoltClock I never said that in my response. I said that in my commenting and referring to the situation. And please tell me something you have to strictly specify as being inherited??

Comment: @MichaelRader He meant your response to the question asked about your answer, not your answer itself.  And he also states that `display` is not automatically inherited.  Neither is float (because nested items are not floated inside of the floating item just because the floated item is floating).

Comment: @James Go read some more CSS books. If you float a parent element with an element inside, like an anchor tag, which is an inline element, it will float with the parent tag. This is the same with DIV's. I suggest you do some research.

Comment: @MichaelRader I really don't understand what your problem is, but the elements inside the floated element are not floating.  Yes, they are moved with the element because they are inside of it, but they are not floated themselves.  Really man, how do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the reason they are showing up in a line is indeed because you heave each `<li>` element floating left.  Your `<a>` tags ARE in block form, but only within each individual `<li>` element.  So if you put more than one `<a>` tag inside the same `<li>` tag, they would stack one on top of the other.  But a block element simply has a width of 100% of the available width.  So in this case, that's the width of the `<li>` tag, which is why the other elements are not pushed down below it.

**Edit**

A better example:

You are telling your `<ul>` tag that you do not want the list items to display as a normal list item in your CSS.  Then, you are telling your `<li>` elements that they will float left.  And since you are not clearing them, they simply float one against the other in a stack until they take up the entire width of whatever they are in.

So, let's say they are just in the body of your page, and the body has a width of 800px, and that each `<li>` takes up 200px.  You would have 4 `<li>` elements in a row before they would drop down a line.

Now, in this case, your "Home" and "About" links would each take up 200px, because they are block elements taking up 100% of their available space, which is 200px (because they are contained inside the `<li>` tags).  They are vertically aligned at the top of the elements they are contained in (by default), and so appear as if they are displaying inline.

But they are not.  It's just that their width is restrained to the available 200px.  If you placed both links within the same `<li>` element, you would see that they stacked on top of each other since each link would take 100% of the available width of the `<li>` element.

If the `<a>` tags were not contained within the `<li>` elements, but directly in the body, their widths would be 800px each, as that is 100% of the available width, and they would stack one on top of the other.